# Plain Text Preview Doesn't Display Special Characters Correctly

Tags: ios, preview, diacritics, print-preview

I have a UTF8 file that I display as a preview to the user via UIDocumentInteractionController. In the preview special characters such as umlauts ä (a with two dots over it) don't display correctly. It looks like a capital A with a box next to it: Ã¤

The file is saved as such:

```
[plainTextContents writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

and displayed via the following:

```
NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
UIDocumentInteractionController* docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:pathURL];
docController.delegate = parentViewController;
```

If I open the saved file on Mac OS X, special characters display as expected. If I iPad preview an RTF version of the file, also saved with NSUTF8StringEncoding, it also looks fine. There's something about the Plain Text preview that is off.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how you add the text to the plain text preview.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're looking for. The second chunk of code I included in my question is how the file gets passed to the UIDocumentInteractionController. Which is what opens a full screen preview of the file.

Comment: Ever got around this? I'm stuck on the exact same problem. Cheers

Comment: I've not found a resolution, and the issue is still persistent with iOS 6.1. Please upvote my question and submit a bug case with Apple. It is more likely to be addressed with greater visibility.